# Android Studio killing ADB server when exiting

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, adb

Every time I close Android Studio, the running instance of the adb server in the background is killed, losing every adb TCP/IP connection previously made.

I'm debugguing particularly shitty devices every and so often, and this is a problem.

Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Not to sound sarcastic, but avoid closing Android Studio?  My instance has been up for months.

Comment: Lucky you. Android Studio (latest version) often hangs and starts leaking huge amounts of memory, especially when using the layout editor. Also, I have other helper tools I've developed on the background making use of ADB. Android Studio is simply not being polite here.

Comment: take a closer look at your *other helper tools you've developed* - you'll find the culprit there

Comment: I can assure you with 100% certainty that is not the case. I've made sure they use the same instance already running by Android Studio. Not to mention it still happens when they are not running.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting called "ADB server lifecycle management", which should do what you're asking for. It expects you to handle everything (including start of adb itself) yourself though.